# How to create a new column column in a dataframe with condition that each label is used when the value is in a list?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame that looks a bit like this:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("A", "dog", 3),
  ("B", "cat", 6),
  ("C", "pink", 5),
  ("D", "eleven", 6),
  ("E", "bird", 98),
  ("F", "green", 75),
  ("G", "five", 7)
).toDF("letter", "category", "value")
```

And I have a some lists of types for the items of the column "category"

```
val animal = Seq[String]("cat","dog","bird","fish","rabbit")
val number = Seq[String]("ten","eleven","twelve","five","six")
val colors = Seq[String]("pink","green","black")
```

And I want to create another column named Type, that says what is the type of the word in the column category, something like this:

```
df
.withColumn("type",
           when($"category".isin(animal), "animal")
           .when($"category".isin(number), "number")
           .when($"category".isin(colors), "colors").otherwise("unclassified"))
```

In this case I used the "isin" just to exemplify the idea. How can I do this.
If I actually try to run this like thid I get:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class
>   scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon List(cat, dog, bird, fish,
>   rabbit)

Also, I think I might have described the problem poorly in the title, but I couldn't find a better way to word it, feel free to give suggestions for another title.

The only way I know to do this would be something like this:

```
df
.withColumn("type",
            when($"category"==="bird"||$"category"==="cat"||$"category"==="dog", "animal")
            .when($"category"==="ten"||$"category"==="eleven"||$"category"==="twelve", "number")
            .when($"category"==="pink"||$"category"==="green"||$"category"==="black", "colors").otherwise("unclassified"))
```

But this it very inefficient

Comment: Apparently all I was missing was a :_* inside the parentheses, like .isin(animal:_*), how embarrassing

Comment: Using full-blown IDEs like `IntelliJ IDEA` instead of plain text-editors such as `Sublime Text` has often helped me nip such mistakes at code-writing phase itself. However wrong and dumb it may sound, I owe a lot to `IntelliJ` for having taught me several concepts of `Scala`